# What moves can follow King K Rool's Down Throw as true combos and at what percentages?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

It is known that King K Rool can score combos after using Down Throw, but this is dependent on the opponent's damage percentage and mashing ability. There is a list of kill confirms from [Down Throw + Up Tilt](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N0SDd33TeUYHfppAxP91M9nQUpe4XyyqGGqyznF3pqk/edit#gid=469218665) and [Down Throw + Forward Tilt](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N0SDd33TeUYHfppAxP91M9nQUpe4XyyqGGqyznF3pqk/edit#gid=571246029), but not one for true combos (inescapable combos regardless of what your opponent does). For Up Tilt and Forward Tilt, they can be true combos at earlier percentages.

Assuming your opponent is perfect at mashing, what true combos can follow King K Rool's Down Throw, and at what percentages? Note that mashing well can greatly reduce the time buried even with >150% - [here's an example](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/a6zx2f/how_do_players_wiggle_so_quickly_out_of_bury/).

Down Throw + Up Smash can also be used against opponents who mash, but it relies on the opponent unburying to hit it with Up Smash. [Down Throw + Up Special cannot form a true combo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/347691/is-king-k-rools-down-throw-to-up-special-a-true-combo/347699#347699).

Comment: It looks like up-tilt takes [9 frames to come out](https://smashboards.com/threads/frame-data-hitbox-data-update-12-12018.464928/) for the upper hit and the opponent will have 12 frames where they cant do anything after they pop out of the bury...so it should just be a matter of whether the FAF after down throw + 9 up-tilt frames is less than their bury time with mashing + 12 pop-out frames. (I don't have the formula for K. Rool's bury time vs. percent or a switch to test down-throw FAF, but if you or someone else has those numbers or the resources, that'd be your answer).

Comment: Looks like the [K. Rool bury formula](https://twitter.com/Meshima_/status/1090519949418815490) is actually just `60 + .75 * (opponent%)` frames. Perfect mashing would be one input per frame that [reduces the bury by 15 frames](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/345753/222207), so divide that formula by 15 essentially. Mean bury time with perfect mashing will be `4 + .05 * (opponent%)` frames. Again, I don't have a switch to test FAF on down throw, but if you have that then the math for whether any move is true at any percent becomes fairly trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've started calculating the maths with your equation using R. It's more complicated since not every move connects with a buried opponent immediately out of dthrow. Some moves require you to move closer and/or jump in order to connect, which adds frames. It'd be difficult (but possible) to determine how many frames all of those moves add. There's also moves like Up Special that can't connect with a buried opponent unless they're on a platform, which would be excluded from the equation